# java.lang.NullPointerException Issue

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-logcat

I realize this is an easy issue usually, but I've been looking at other similar questions on this site and others and have not been able to fix the code, nor seeing exactly where the error is coming from. What seems to be my problem is calling an OnClickListener assigned to a button, but then again I could be wrong. I had basically straight copied this code (with minimal changes) from another application where this had worked. This fact baffles me a little bit more. Thanks in advance for your help with this relatively easy question.

Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.update_activity);

    final Handler handler;
    handler = new Handler();

    final EditText getCustID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer);
    final EditText custvar1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var1);
    final EditText custvar2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var2);
    final EditText custvar3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var3);

    class sendGET implements Runnable
    {
        private String url;

        public sendGET(String mUrl)
        {
            url = mUrl;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                //Declare HttpClient and HttpGet
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

                //Run HttpGet
                client.execute(httpget);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class getCustomerData implements Runnable
    {       
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream stream = null;
                XMLparser xmlParser = new XMLparser();
                List<Customer> customers = null;

                String parseUrl = URL + getCustID.getText().toString();

                try
                {
                    stream = downloadUrl(parseUrl);
                    customers = xmlParser.parse(stream);
                }
                finally
                {
                    stream.close();
                }

                final Customer data = customers.get(0);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        custvar1.setText(String.valueOf(data.var1));
                        custvar2.setText(String.valueOf(data.var2));
                        custvar3.setText(String.valueOf(data.var3));
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                //return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
            }
        }

        private Customer readCustomer(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
        {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "customer");
            String custID = null;
            String var1 = null;
            String var2 = null;
            String var3 = null;

            while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("CustID"))
                {
                    custID = readCustID(parser);
                } else if (name.equals("custvar1"))
                {
                    var1 = readVar1(parser);
                } else if (name.equals("custvar2"))
                {
                    var2 = readVar2(parser);
                } else if (name.equals("custvar3"))
                {
                    var3 = readVar3(parser);
                } else
                {
                    skip(parser);
                }

            }
            return new Customer(custID, var1, var2, var3);
        }

        private String readCustID(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "CustID");
            final String custID = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "CustID");
            return custID;
        }

        private String readVar1(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "custvar1");
            String var1 = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "custvar1");
            return var1;
        }

        private String readVar2(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "custvar2");
            String var2 = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "custvar2");
            return var2;
        }

        private String readVar3(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "custvar3");
            String var3 = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "custvar3");
            return var3;
        }

        private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            String result = "";
            if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
            {
                result = parser.getText();
                parser.nextTag();
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
        {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0)
            {
                switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth --;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        class XMLparser
        {       
            public List<Customer> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                try
                {
                    XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                    parser.setInput(in, null);
                    parser.nextTag();
                    return readXML(parser);
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }

            private List<Customer> readXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
            {
                List<Customer> custData = new ArrayList<Customer>();

                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "xml");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();

                    //Look for customer tag
                    if (name.equals("customer"))
                    {
                        custData.add(readCustomer(parser));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }

                return custData;
            }
        }

        private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            //start the query
            conn.connect();
            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            return stream;
        }
    }

    final Button getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    getData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Declare and start thread
            final Runnable mGetData = new getCustomerData();
            final Thread getData = new Thread(mGetData);
            getData.start();
        }
    });

    final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //set url
            String url = "**removed**";
            url += "var1=" + custvar1.getText().toString() + "&var2=" + custvar2.getText().toString() + "&var3=" + custvar3.getText().toString();

            //Declare and start thread
            final Runnable mConnect = new sendGET(url);
            final Thread Connect = new Thread(mConnect);
            Connect.start();
        }
    });
}

public class Customer
{
    public final String custID;
    public final String var1;
    public final String var2;
    public final String var3;

    private Customer()
    {
        custID = null;
        var1 = null;
        var2 = null;
        var3 = null;
    }

    private Customer(String custID, String var1, String var2, String var3)
    {
        this.custID = custID;
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
        this.var3 = var3;

    }
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
01-09 19:20:53.478: W/dalvikvm(911): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
01-09 19:20:53.478: E/AndroidRuntime(911): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-99
01-09 19:20:53.478: E/AndroidRuntime(911): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 19:20:53.478: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at us.rns.editdata.UpdateActivity$1getCustomerData.run(UpdateActivity.java:90)
01-09 19:20:53.478: E/AndroidRuntime(911):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-09 19:20:54.408: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(911): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: what line is this throwing the exception on?

Comment: Stop using "logcat debugging". Attach the debugger. Stop on the exception (when it's thrown). Inspect the expression(s) on the relevant line to find out which is null.

Comment: It seems to be throwing the exception on the line: "stream.close();" If I'm reading the debugger right, but that makes even less sense to me.

Comment: @Jim it makes perfect sense.  Your downloadUrl method is failing, the Exception is caught, and `stream` is still null at that point.

Comment: So then I guess that means that trying to do a string concatenation is causing an error in the URL. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure.  You'll have to debug through the `downloadUrl method and see exactly what line is causing the issue.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, well now it works. I did move the "final Button....." declarations up to the top with the textview declarations. Could that have made a difference?

Comment: @Jim probably not at this point.  But glad that it works.  Was it moving the buttons, or changing the downloadUrl method that fixed it?  Please let me know and I will change my answer to reflect the solution so you can mark it as answered.

Comment: I honestly moved the two declaration lines up and that was the only change I made to my code. It worked after that. And I'll gladly mark it as answered. Thanks for helping me with this as messy of a program as it is to read.

Comment: @Jim thanks for getting back and marking it as answered, I added the original solution to me post.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I added the if (stream != null) and I'll keep the onResume suggestion in mind as well. This project is only in the beginning stages for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your downloadUrl method is failing.

```
InputStream stream = null;
XMLparser xmlParser = new XMLparser();
List<Customer> customers = null;

String parseUrl = URL + getCustID.getText().toString();

try
{
    stream = downloadUrl(parseUrl);
    customers = xmlParser.parse(stream);
}
finally
{
    stream.close();
}
```

The stream object is set to null, then you assign `stream  = downloadUrl(parseUrl)`.

The downloadUrl method fails, without having assigned anything to `stream`.

You then try to close the stream in the `finally` clause.

```
private InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    //start the query
    conn.connect();
    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
    return stream;
}
```

Put a breakpoint on this method, and debug through it.  Please return with the exact line it is breaking on.  I suspect it is `conn.connect();` or `InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();`

I would also do this in the finally clause:

```
finally
{
    if(stream != null)
        stream.close();
}
```

It could also be the following:

You need to move all of these:

```
final EditText getCustID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer);
final EditText custvar1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var1);
final EditText custvar2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var2);
final EditText custvar3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.var3);

final Button getData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getData);

final Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Submit);
```

into onResume, rather than onCreate()

Comment: @A--C the last two are static fields in the class, and this would cause a NullRefException because they are not instantiated (as the `View` has not been drawn yet)

Comment: God, private classes everywhere.  I'm running away now.

Comment: I currently don't have an onResume method. Should I create one then? Why would this make a difference in the code being run?

Comment: @Jim A--C may be right, but I always put all of my UI/runnable stuff in onResume, because it is the last step before the view is displayed to the user.

Comment: What should the onResume look like then?

Comment: I see those 2 buttons now. Way at the end. Also, @Jim, put them in `onCreate()`, since `onResume()` is called every time the user comes in and out of your Activty, which makes for wasteful calls.

Comment: @A--C I corrected my answer.  Could you please reverse your downvote, or explain what is still wrong with it?

Comment: Ah, no worries then, thanks for the tip on Android, I didn't think of it that way before.  Appreciate the help!